# Logstash process getting killed when csv has large columns

Tags: python, linux, kubernetes, operating-system, logstash

I have a pod of 6gb ram and storage and i have been using logstash to sync the data from csv to Elastic Search but logstash process is getting killed  after syncing some data. I have tried it with min 1 worker 500 batch too

```
**CSV chunk** {
Rows=> 5 million 
columns=> 641
}

**pod configuration** 
{
ram=> 6gb
storage => 6gb
}

**logstash config** :- 
input {  
        file {
                path => "/app/table1.csv" #ssv of 5m rows rows and 641 columns  
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                ignore_older => 36000000 
                close_older => 36000000
            } 
        }
        
        filter {
            csv {
                separator => ";"#csv separator 
                remove_field => ["message"]
                
}}

output { 
                elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
                    index => "activity_test04232_3"
                    retry_max_interval => 5
                    retry_initial_interval => 30
                }#output ES host 
            }
```

Comment: Any logs suggest the reason for the pod to get killed?

Comment: jabbson pod  is not getting killed but the logstash process is getting killed which is running inside the pod ,In parallel  I was hitting  logstash node api in which cpu usage become 80 % after few seconds  and  then logstash process gets killed ,Don't know the reason why logstash is taking so much memory

Comment: Do you have anything in the logstash logs?

Comment: No leandrokmp i did  not find anything in logs  but I got some workaround after googling for hours  ,I set these variables  export LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms1024m"  then  with 8 workers and 1500 batches it is working fine ,above that cpu usage is increasing and process getting killed

Comment: Your comments are hard to understand: is your cpu 80% or memory too high?

Comment: M.Mavini yes  logstash cpu usage is too high because I am using filter in my logstash conf, so to  solve this issue I decrease the heap size ,After decreasing the heap my sync process became slow but my logstash process is not getting killed because of high CPU Usage

Comment: Did you try to follow [this Performance Checklist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/performance-troubleshooting.html) for diagnose Logstash performance problems?